# Select invoices based on quantity needed

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table that looks like this:

```
+---------------+---------------+------------------+--------------+
| InvoiceNumber | ProductNumber | ReceivedQuantity | ReceivedDate |
+---------------+---------------+------------------+--------------+
| INV001        | P001          |              500 |   09/01/2015 |
| INV002        | P001          |              600 |   09/02/2015 |
| INV003        | P001          |              700 |   09/03/2015 |
+---------------+---------------+------------------+--------------+
```

When a product is ordered. System needs to know which invoice it gets it from. First in first out.

For example I need 1000 quantity of product number `P001`. It should select the following invoices. It does not display the last invoice since 500 + 600 is already sufficient quantity

```
+---------------+---------------+------------------+--------------+
| InvoiceNumber | ProductNumber | ReceivedQuantity | ReceivedDate |
+---------------+---------------+------------------+--------------+
| INV001        | P001          |              500 |   09/01/2015 |
| INV002        | P001          |              600 |   09/02/2015 |
+---------------+---------------+------------------+--------------+
```

I can replicate this by making a cursor and looping through the table but looking for the best way to achieve this. Any nudge to the right direction would help a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use a query like this:

```
;WITH t As (
    SELECT *
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ReceivedDate, InvoiceNumber) As RowNo
    FROM yourTable
), firstOverflow AS (
    SELECT TOP(1)
        t1.RowNo
    FROM t t1
        LEFT JOIN
        t t2 ON t1.ProductNumber = t2.ProductNumber AND t1.ReceivedDate >= t2.ReceivedDate
    GROUP BY t1.RowNo, t1.InvoiceNumber, t1.ProductNumber, t1.ReceivedQuantity, t1.ReceivedDate
    HAVING SUM(t2.ReceivedQuantity) >= 1000
    ORDER BY SUM(t2.ReceivedQuantity) - 1000)
SELECT *
FROM t 
    JOIN 
    firstOverflow ON t.RowNo <= firstOverflow.RowNo;
```

A better solution is this:

```
DECLARE @value int = 1000;

WITH t As (
    SELECT *
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ReceivedDate, InvoiceNumber) As seq
    FROM yourTable
), s As (
    SELECT t.InvoiceNumber, t.ProductNumber, t.ReceivedQuantity, t.ReceivedDate, SUM(tt.ReceivedQuantity) As currentTotal
    FROM t
        LEFT JOIN
        t tt ON t.ProductNumber = tt.ProductNumber AND  t.seq >= tt.seq
    GROUP BY t.InvoiceNumber, t.ProductNumber, t.ReceivedQuantity, t.ReceivedDate
), st As (
    SELECT *
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (CASE WHEN s.currentTotal > @value THEN -currentTotal ELSE Null END) DESC) As seq
    FROM s)
SELECT st.InvoiceNumber, st.ProductNumber, st.ReceivedQuantity, st.ReceivedDate
FROM st
WHERE currentTotal < @value
UNION ALL
SELECT st.InvoiceNumber, st.ProductNumber, st.ReceivedQuantity, st.ReceivedDate
FROM st
WHERE currentTotal >= @value AND st.seq = 1;
```

Comment: Although if the quantity in question is more than the invoice quantity it doesn't return any rows.

Comment: If i use left join it displays everything. But anyway I think it correct to not show any rows if the quantity is not sufficient. It just means the quantity needed is more than the stocks. Thanks man. Appreciate the help. Will wait a little a while for better answers then will accept yours. Lets just use JOIN in the last select statement

Answer (score 0):

Try this query and give some feedback:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (InvoiceNumber nvarchar(100),
                      ProductNumber nvarchar(100),
                      ReceivedQuantity int)
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('inv001', 'p001', 500)
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('inv002', 'p001', 600)
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('inv003', 'p001', 600)
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('inv004', 'p001', 600)
```

SQL 2012:

```
SELECT v.* FROM
(
    SELECT t.*,
      SUM(ReceivedQuantity) OVER (PARTITION BY ProductNumber ORDER BY InvoiceNumber) AS sum
    FROM @table t
) v
WHERE sum <= 1000
```

SQL 2008:

```
SELECT v.* FROM
(
SELECT
    a.InvoiceNumber
    , a.ProductNumber
    , SUM(b.ReceivedQuantity) AS sum
FROM
    @table a
    INNER JOIN @table b
    ON  a.InvoiceNumber >= b.InvoiceNumber AND a.ProductNumber = b.ProductNumber
GROUP BY 
    a.InvoiceNumber
    , a.ProductNumber
) v
WHERE sum <= 1000
```

Comment: I tried query in MS SQL and it works. What do you mean with wrong syntax?

Comment: Copy everything to SSMS and give it a try.

Comment: @AljPra I think `SUM(..) OVER (...)` is not present in SQL Server 2008 ;).

Comment: That was not mentioned. I added solution for SQL 2008 and SQL 2012.

Comment: sql 2008 was in the question tags. Anyway ran your sql query and it returned only 1 row